# Thumbnail image swap with overlay

Tags: jquery, hover, overlay, thumbnails, mousemove

I have this thumbnail image slider on mousemove.

**Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/t2qw9b10/**

Now I introduced an hover overlay to show info text. But with said overlay the image slider doesn't work anymore. I know I have to change the target from `$(".imageHolder")` (the data-image-list) to `$(.info)` (the hover overlay) at least. Any ideas on what else I have to adjust to make it work?

I have experience with html/css but no experience with javascript. Would love to get some insight how I can fix thus. I appreciate the help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

there are a few issues with your js, firstly the xPos will always be greater than change1 so you replacing the src more times than you need to, as this will run on every moment of the mouse, rather look to use else if, also check if the src has already been set and look to check if xPos is between ranges, I'm not sure what effect your going for so I just put in a simple fade out old image out and fade new image in

```js
$(".imageHolder").mousemove(function(event) {
  var xPos = event.pageX,
    imgPos = $(this).offset().left,
    imgWidth = $(this).width();
  var change1 = imgPos,
    change2 = imgPos + imgWidth / 3,
    change3 = imgPos + (2 * imgWidth) / 3;
  // console.log("change1: ", change1, "change2: ", change2, "change3: ", change3);
  $images = $(this).parent("figure").data("imageList");

  var array = $images.split(",");
  if (xPos > change1 && xPos < change2 && xPos < change3 && $(this).attr("src") !== array[0]) {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $(this).attr('src', array[0]);
      $(this).fadeIn('fast');
    });
  } else if (xPos > change2 && xPos < change3 && $(this).attr("src") !== array[1]) {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $(this).attr('src', array[1]);
      $(this).fadeIn('fast');
    });
  } else if (xPos > change3 && $(this).attr("src") !== array[2]) {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $(this).attr('src', array[2]);
      $(this).fadeIn('fast');
    });
  }
});

$("img").mouseout(function() {
  $(this).attr("src", $("img").data("src"));
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.info {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 15px;
  left: 39px;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.info:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.author {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <figure data-image-list="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/cccccc.png&text=img1,http://dummyimage.com/200x200/dedede/cccccc.png&text=img2,http://dummyimage.com/200x200/b31031/cccccc.png&text=img3">
      <img class="imageHolder" data-src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/cdcdcd/dddddd.png&text=+" src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/cdcdcd/dddddd.png&text=+" />
    </figure>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="author">mccoolguy</div>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <figure data-image-list="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/cccccc.png&text=img1,http://dummyimage.com/200x200/dedede/cccccc.png&text=img2,http://dummyimage.com/200x200/b31031/cccccc.png&text=img3">
      <img class="imageHolder" data-src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/cdcdcd/dddddd.png&text=+" src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/cdcdcd/dddddd.png&text=+" />
    </figure>
  </article>

  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

This only apply to the src change on the imageHolder, not sure what you were going for with the overlay to show info text sorry ? I hope this helps any way